# Can I add conditions within Kendo().DropDownList() definition?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have a kendo dropdownlist and want to add a property to it but only if some condition is met. It that possible and, if so, what is the syntax? Below is the concept that I have in mind.

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("My Dropdown List")
    .Value(Model.xxx)
     If (some condition){
       .Height(1000)
     }
    .DataTextField("MYDESCRIPTIEN")
    .DataValueField("MYFIELD")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi there you should be able to add **Events** like so:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("My Dropdown List")
    .Value(Model.xxx)
    .DataTextField("MYDESCRIPTIEN")
    .DataValueField("MYFIELD")
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
    .Events(e => e.Change("OnDropDownChanged"));
)
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
function OnDropDownChanged(e)
{
     //Do stuff to meet condition
}
```

Comment: can this be done on page load, not "onChange"? I added some info to my question, so the concept I have in mind should be more clear (sorry if the question wasn't described well enough before)

Comment: Yes this can be done on page load. You can use the 'Events' to bind to a condition and then set the property explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** With regard to the Height, I am afraid you are out of luck, as the Height() method expects a non-null integer value that will be always serialized to the client. The only option is to use two different widget declarations inside an external conditional statement.

===

Each fluent method expects a value of a certain type, or an expression that returns a value of this type. In addition, each configuration setting has a default value.

So you have a couple of options:

- use a ternary operator that returns different values, depending on the condition. In one case it may return the property's default value
- use an auxiliary variable, that is assigned the appropriate value in advance

Fluent methods that expect an action can be managed differently and you can use standard conditional statements, instead of ternaries.

Here is an example for all above scenarios:

```
@{     
   bool myCondition = false;
}

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .HtmlAttributes(myCondition ? new { style = "width: 100%" } : new object { /* empty object */ } )
     .Events(e => {

          if (myCondition)
          {
              // nothing here this time
          }
          else
          {
              e.DataBound("onDataBound");
          }

    })
)

<script>

    function onDataBound(e) {
        console.log("dataBound");
    }

</script>
```